# Combine two RxJS streams (based on synchrony)

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have two RxJS subjects, say `a` and `b` that I need to combine somehow.

```
someComboOfAandB.subscribe({aVal, bVal} => console.log("value:", aVal, bVal));
```

I want to combine them such that if `a` and `b` are updated synchronously, the values are delivered together:

```
a.next(1);
// some code
b.next(2)

// at end of synchronous code / frame:
// value: 1 2
```

However, if just one value is updated, an update will still be pushed at the same time an update with two new values would be pushed:

```
a.next(5)

// at end of synchronous code / frame:
// value: 5 2
```

Is this possible? If it is, how so? Even if it is possible, is it something that should be avoided?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz The problem is that two updates would get triggered in the first example above, which I can't have.

Comment: How about `withLatestFrom`? Will only emit when one of the streams emit.

Comment: Or maybe what you're looking for is `combineLatest(...).debounceTime(...)`

Comment: `debounceTime` is interesting, but I'm not sure what sort of guarantees on time I could know. For example, what if the code between `a.next` and `b.next` takes 1ms? 12ms? etc. Maybe a `debounce` paired with `requestAnimationFrame` somehow?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `requestAnimationFrame` but yeah you'd need to know how long the code between `a.next` and `b.next` would take. Although if they are the only two calls that are being made close to each other you could be quite conservative and pass in a large value like e.g. 500ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able use a `Scheduler` to effect the behavior you want:

```
import "rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { asap } from "rxjs/scheduler/asap";

let a = new BehaviorSubject(1);
let b = new BehaviorSubject(2);
let combined = Observable
    .combineLatest(a, b, asap)
    .map((values) => ({ aVal: values[0], bVal: values[1] }));

combined.subscribe(
    ({ aVal, bVal }) => { console.log("value:", aVal, bVal); }
);

a.next(3);
b.next(4);
```

The above code will output the following:

```
value: 3 4
```

If the `asap` `Scheduler` is not specified, the output would be:

```
value: 1 2
value: 3 2
value: 3 4
```

The RxJS GitHub repo contains some [`Scheduler` documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md).

Comment: According to the docs, `asap` "Schedules on the micro task queue, which uses the fastest transport mechanism available, either ... Web Worker MessageChannel or setTimeout or others." This sounds very promising, I'll give it a try tomorrow

Comment: Tried this out in my code, and interestingly `asap` didn't work, but `async` did. I guess I'm not clear on the difference between the two in the context of a browser

Comment: Hmm, this is frustrating - sometimes it seems to work, sometimes it doesn't. I have a place in my code base basically as such: `log("start"); a.next(1); log("mid"); b.next(2);` And I get `"start", "subscription update", "mid"`, where the subscriber gets an update synchronously with `a.next`. before `b.next` is called. Other times it works though :/

Comment: What RxJS version are you using? [This PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/1820) was merged in 5.0.0-beta.11: "The AsapScheduler and AnimationFrameScheduler were totally busted"

Comment: You're exactly right - was using `5.0.0-beta.6`. Thanks for the quality answer and insight about the versions!